# regexp pattern help java/groovy

Tags: java, regex, parsing, groovy

I'm trying to parse something like this:
`Key1=[val123, val456], Key2=[val78, val123]`

into a `Map<String, List<String>>`
A prob is that both the key and values could have non-alpha num characters like `.:-_`

This looks like something I should be able to use the regexp pattern match/group thing to make short work of without parsing, but I'm not having any luck getting the regex expression working. Any regexp gurus?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*\[\s*([^\s,]+),\s*([^\s,]+)\s*\]
```

This will match one key/values pair and extract the key in backreference 1, the first value in backreference 2 and the second value in backreference 3.

In Java this could look something like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^=\\s]+)\\s*=\\s*\\[\\s*([^\\s,]+),\\s*([^\\s,]+)\\s*\\]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    key  = regexMatcher.group(1);
    val1 = regexMatcher.group(2);
    val2 = regexMatcher.group(3);
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
([^=\s]+)   # Match one or more characters except whitespace or =
\s*=\s*     # Match =, optionally surrounded by whitespace
\[\s*       # Match [ plus optional whitespace
([^\s,]+)   # Match anything except spaces or commas
,\s*        # Match a comma plus optional whitespace
([^\s,]+)   # Match anything except spaces or commas
\s*\]       # Match optional whitespace and ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way in Groovy:

```
import java.util.regex.*

def map = [:]
def matcher = "Key1=[val123, val456], Key2=[val78, val123, val666]" =~ /(\S+)=\[([^]]*)]/
matcher.each { 
  map.put(it[1], it[2].split(/,\s*/)) 
}
println map
```

which produces:

```
[Key1:[val123, val456], Key2:[val78, val123, val666]]
```

Test rig can be found here: http://ideone.com/6oFsU

Comment: Thanks Bart, I combined your regexp and Tim's to come up with `([^=\s]+)\s*=\s*\[([^]]*)]`  Appreciate your assistance

Comment: It’s a shame that Java’s `\S` matches whitespace. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get your example to work using this Groovy:

```
def str = 'Key1=[val123, val456], Key2=[val78, val123]'

class Evaluator extends Binding {
  def parse( s ) {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell( this );
    shell.evaluate( s )
  }
  Object getVariable( String name ) { name }
}

new Evaluator().parse "[$str]".tr( '=', ':' )
```

But you say you can have more complex examples?

The best, safest solution would be to get the program generating the output to use a proper data format such as xml or json

However (of course) this is not always possible

Comment: Yes, I had considered this but unfortunately the input string is (untrusted) user entered, so for security reasons this was a no-go. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic way building on Bart's method:

```
def map = [:]
("Key1=[val123, val456], Key2=[val78, val123, val666]" =~ /(\S+)=\[([^]]*)]/ ).each { text, key, value ->
    map[key] = value.split(/,\s*/)
}
```